# How To Integrate Saml In .Net Core Application Step by Step

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

I am worried how to integrate *SAML*. I tried to go through the documentation, but I did not find anything useful. Can any one help me out of this problem please ?

Comment: Take a look at [I need a SAML stack](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the reference!

Yes - there are three products there that will provide SAML support for .NET Core.

- Sustainsys - Free
- ComponentSpace - Commercial
- Rock Solid Knowledge - Commercial built around identityserver4